# Custom API endpoint for WooCommerce Add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have been trying to build a custom api endpoint to add to cart. My local is working fine and adding the product to the cart easily. I made the code live and getting an error like:

```
Call to a member function generate_cart_id() on null
```

Here is the code I have written.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route( 'product/v1', 'add_to_cart',array(
                'methods'  => 'POST',
                'callback' => 'wplms_add_to_cart'
      ));
});

function wplms_add_to_cart($request) {

    $product_id = $request['product_id'];
    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($product_id);

    if( ! WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id ) ){
        // The product ID is NOT in the cart, let's add it then!
        $added = $cart->add_to_cart( $product_id);
    }


    $response = new WP_REST_Response(var_dump($added));
    $response->set_status(200);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wc-cart-is-null-in-custom-rest-api/ or https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/23792 or https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/27160

Answer (score 2):

The way I resolved it.

```
if ( defined( 'WC_ABSPATH' ) ) {
    // WC 3.6+ - Cart and other frontend functions are not included for REST requests.
    include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-cart-functions.php';
    include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-notice-functions.php';
            include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-template-hooks.php';
}

if ( null === WC()->session ) {
    $session_class = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_session_handler', 'WC_Session_Handler' );

    WC()->session = new $session_class();
    WC()->session->init();
}

if ( null === WC()->customer ) {
    WC()->customer = new WC_Customer( get_current_user_id(), true );
}

if ( null === WC()->cart ) {
    WC()->cart = new WC_Cart();

    // We need to force a refresh of the cart contents from session here (cart contents are normally refreshed on wp_loaded, which has already happened by this point).
    $cart  = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($request['product_id']);
    $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart($product_cart_id);
    if (!$cart_item_key) {
        $add = WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id = $request['product_id'], $quantity = 1, $variation_id = 0, $variation = array(), $cart_item_data = array() );
    } else {
        $add = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Just needs  WC()->frontend_includes(); to work at 2021.

Comment: will this know which cart belongs to who? let's say we have the FE in vercel and the woo backend in siteground, we know that cart system in woo works with cookie sessions. would there be any issues with "ghost" products when a lot of people are adding items to cart at the same time?

Comment: Can you explain what is the parameter structure for API

Comment: It depends how you set the parameter.